# PHP Hello World Program

Tags: php

Hi I'm making a quick PHP program that takes in an integer (x) and prints the numbers from 1 to that number.

- If the number is divisible by 3 then print "Hello".
- If the number is divisible by 7 print "World".
- If the number is divisible by 3 & 7, print "Hello World".

The output is nothing.

```
$var = 0;   
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     for ($i = 1; $i < $var; $i++) 
     {
          if ($var % 3 == 0)
          {
            echo 'Hello' . "\n"; 
          }           

          if ($var % 7 == 0)            
          {
            echo 'World'. "\n";
          }

          if (($var % 7 == 0) && ($var % 3 == 0))
          {
            echo 'Hello World'. "\n";
          } else {
            echo "";
          }
     }      
}
```

Comment: You should do `else { echo 'Nothing'; }` in order to just be sure you have been entering in the `for` loop.

Comment: You appreciate that you'll get some instances of `Hello Hello World` and of `World Hello World`?

Comment: Just added an answer that might suit your question. Please feel free to review it.

Comment: And surely you should also be testing for `if ($i % 3 == 0)` not for `if ($var % 3 == 0)`?

Comment: So, where's `$var=$_POST['var'];` in your question to support `<input type="int" class="form-control input-sm" input name="var" placeholder="Enter an Integer">`? Or, should we fill that in for you?

Comment: ^ fallen onto deaf ears ^

Comment: Ok, so where are we at with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $var is always = to 0.
And you should test if ($var % 7 == 0) && ($var % 3 == 0) at first 
and add else if. Because here if ($var % 7 == 0) && ($var % 3 == 0) the output will be Hello World Hello World. All the if will be executed.

Here the correct code :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $var = $_POST['var'];
     for ($i = 1; $i < $var; $i++) 
      {
          if (($var % 7 == 0) && ($var % 3 == 0))
          {
            echo 'Hello World'. "\n";
          }
          else if ($var % 3 == 0)
          {
            echo 'Hello' . "\n"; 
          }           
          else if ($var % 7 == 0)            
          {
            echo 'World'. "\n";
          }          
          else {
            echo "Nothing";
          }
       }      
    }
```

Comment: `$var = $_POST['submit'];` that should be `$var = $_POST['var'];` as per their `<input type="int" class="form-control input-sm" input name="var" placeholder="Enter an Integer">`

Comment: Thank for the upvote :) And for the POST var you right, i just took the same var name.

Comment: Try to display your POST var to see if you defined the $_POST['submit'] in a previous form. You can do that with `var_dump($_POST)`. 
If you did that in your URI ?submit=12 then you have to use the $_GET.

Comment: Sorry, I marked it as solved,  thank for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you've posted the correct code (meaning without typo), that's perfectly normal the output is nothing.

Look at what you wrote:

```
$var = 0;
```

Then you do

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $var; $i++) {}
```

No wonder why nothing is output. It is exactly the same as doing

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 0; $i++) {}
```

`$i` is never `<` to `0`. So the `for` loop is never launched.

You need to set `$var` to store the user input from your form submission.

Comment: Your answer has more information than mine & was quicker. +1 :)